# using async function into loop with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have to check if foreignKey exist, but I can't make a loop with my asynchronous query function

```
function checkAllFK(tables, foreignKeys) {
  let index = -1;
  for (var key in foreignKeys) {
    index++;
    QueryFunction(tables[index], key, foreignKeys[key])
    .then(result => {
    if(result == null) {
      //here, if result is null, that's mean the foreignKey doesn't exist, then, we have to stop the loop and return false;
      return false;
    }
    else if(index == (tables.length - 1)) {
      //here, that's mean we are at the end of the loop, and we doesn't break it with the previous if, that's mean all foreignKey exist, then, we return true;
      return true;
    }
  }
```

the problem is that at the end of the first iteration, you exit the function and the result of the return depends only on the first iteration: false if the if condition is met at the first iteration, null if not

even having looked at many similar topics here, I haven't found a solution to my problem.

Comment: Try investigating async await and promises..

Comment: How about wrapping a Promise around your QueryFunction so you can simply call it from an async function while using await in your loop?

Comment: Don't write these kinds of one-by-one loops over SQL tables in the first place. This is extremely inefficient. SQL has set operations for that, these things can be found out in a single SQL statement.

Answer (score 2):

Your operation "check all `foreignKeys` against all `tables`" can be written in one line.

```
function checkAllFK(tables, foreignKeys) {
  return Promise.all(tables.map(t => Promise.all(foreignKeys.map(k => QueryFunction(t, k))));
}
```

This function returns a promise that resolves when all queries are done, so you call it like

```
checkAllFK(tables, foreignKeys)
    .then(/* success */)
    .catch(/* error */);
```

However, depending on how many `foreignKeys` and `tables` there are and how complex `QueryFunction` is, this can put enormous stress on the database server. If there are 10 tables and 1000 foreign keys, this would attempt to run 10,000 queries in parallel against the database server. This is not a smart thing to do.

SQL is made to handle these situations. Instead of running 10,000 queries for one thing each, you can decide to run one query for 10,000 things. Or 10 queries for 1000 things each. Both are obviously better than hammering the database server with 10,000 requests.

For example, this returns all foreign keys that do not exist in `table_1` in one step.

```
SELECT
  k.key_column
FROM
  foreign_keys k
  LEFT JOIN table_1 t ON t.key_column = k.key_column
WHERE
  t.key_column IS NULL
```

It depends on what you do in your `QueryFunction` how the actual SQL needs to look like.

The fact that you have more than one table to check the same foreign keys against is worrying as well, this usually is an indication of poor database design.

Comment: Yes, very much.  At _least_ use `Promise.all`, or better is a single query if possible.  Nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

there is few common begginer mistakes. Lets start with the tricky one and it is using `var` keyword in a for-loop in asynchronous context. As you can see, this will return you only `10`s, not `1, 2, 3`.

```js
for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 100);
}
```

Fix is easy in this case - just use `let`, which has different scope than `var` and works as you would expect.

```js
    for (let i=0; i < 10; i++) {
      setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 100);
    }
```

Second is asynchronous context - the for-cycle ends before you execute the async context inside the promise that is returned by QueryFunction. If you can use newer version of Node.js then `async/await` is your saviour, just mark your function as `async` and have

`const result = await QueryFunction(tables[index], key, foreignKeys[key])`

However be awared - once you have something in Promise/Asynchronous context, you basically cant get back to the synchronous context. So all your logic needs be aware that you are in asynchronous part. That basically means that all the results will be promises and you will need to `then` them or `await` them. Its not bug or something, its behaviour and you need to count on that.

Comment: And the third issue is that the OP would be *much* better off with a single SQL statement that uses a JOIN or a EXISTS operation instead of checking keys one-by-one from the client end.

Answer (score 0):

you can do same like print a message in the console or write in a file, can get the visual result.

if you want to get a result,  use 'wait', please.

Comment: This really isn't an answer, and would be better suited as a comment.  When you gain more reputation, you'll be able to add comments....